# Standard Wordpress installation migrate to Kubernetes bitnami/wordpress

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes, cloud, devops, bitnami

I have stanard wordpress installation on my server with all plugins, themes and stuff. Now I want to migrate to kubernetes server where I have already installed bitnami/wordpress. I see a bit other structure of files in bitnami/Wordpress installation on kubernetes where is only wp-content and config file in main folder of wordpress.

Can I copy normal Wordpress installation to Kubernetes image bitnami/wordpress installation from image installed by helm? How will be to do it best? Should I do it like normal wordpress website or other technique and tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here,

The app's files are now inside the /opt/bitnami/wordpress directory. We recently updated all our WordPress cloud solutions to have the same directory structure. However, it seems that you have a previous version of the solution deployed in the cloud our you used the Bitnami installer in your server.

The easiest way to migrate your data from your current server to the k8s deployment is by using the [All in One WP Migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) plugin. The plugin takes care of saving all the necessary data so you just need to recover that data in the new deployment. You won't need to copy any other file from the deployment when using this plugin.